# How to combine to values from two records

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi guys so I have the following code that should look at a event cost, figure out from a transaction table if its been fully paid and from that display the unpaid balance.

```
Select CASESTUDY_CLIENT.CLEINT_FNAME as First_Name,  
       casestudy_client.client_sname as Surname, 
       casestudy_client.client_Phonenumber as Phone_number, 
       casestudy_event.event_totalcost- casestudy_transaction.transaction_value as Unpaid_balance
  from casestudy_client
  inner join casestudy_event
    on casestudy_client.client_id = casestudy_event.event_clientid
  inner join casestudy_transaction
    on casestudy_event.event_id = casestudy_transaction.transaction_eventid
  where casestudy_event.EVENT_EVENTSTAGE ='complete' and 
        casestudy_event.event_totalcost > casestudy_transaction.transaction_value;
```

This works perfectly however if we have a multi part transaction then it fails to pick up the matching event id and assumes its another event.

In my test data I have an event that costs £500, one transaction that has a value of 400 and one transaction with a value of 99. The current output shows the two records one with an unpaid balance of 100 and the other with 401. What I would like to show is just 99

If this is possible in relatively simple way please let me know as I can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Why would you show 99? It appears that the unpaid balance would be 1. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add together transactions.

```
Select CASESTUDY_CLIENT.CLEINT_FNAME as First_Name,  
       casestudy_client.client_sname as Surname, 
       casestudy_client.client_Phonenumber as Phone_number, 
       casestudy_event.event_totalcost- sum(casestudy_transaction.transaction_value) as Unpaid_balance
  from casestudy_client
  inner join casestudy_event
    on casestudy_client.client_id = casestudy_event.event_clientid
  inner join casestudy_transaction
    on casestudy_event.event_id = casestudy_transaction.transaction_eventid
  where casestudy_event.EVENT_EVENTSTAGE ='complete' and 
        casestudy_event.event_totalcost > casestudy_transaction.transaction_value
GROUP BY CASESTUDY_CLIENT.CLEINT_FNAME, casestudy_client.client_sname, casestudy_client.client_Phonenumber, casestudy_event.event_totalcost
```

Also, CLEINT_FNAME is probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to sum the transaction values before subtracting them from the cost.

```
Select      CASESTUDY_CLIENT.CLEINT_FNAME as First_Name,
            casestudy_client.client_sname as Surname,
            casestudy_client.client_Phonenumber as Phone_number,
            casestudy_event.event_totalcost- casestudy_transaction.transaction_value as Unpaid_balance
from        casestudy_client
inner join  casestudy_event
    on      casestudy_client.client_id = casestudy_event.event_clientid
inner join  (
    select      casestudy_transaction.transaction_eventid, sum(transaction_value) as transaction_value
    from        casestudy_transaction
    group by    casestudy_transaction.transaction_eventid
    ) as casestudy_transaction
    on      casestudy_event.event_id = casestudy_transaction.transaction_eventid
where       casestudy_event.EVENT_EVENTSTAGE ='complete'
    and     casestudy_event.event_totalcost> casestudy_transaction.transaction_value ;
```

I would probably left join the transactions subquery though so you can include the events that haven't been paid for yet, but that just depends on the goal of the query.

Comment: Great I'll test that out tomorrow, I'll let you know how it goes!